# Python list unexpected behavior?

Tags: python-3.x, breadth-first-search

When trying to do breadth first solution, I came across a unexpected behavior.
In the function levelOrder if the left node is being processed first, then it is giving correct result 3 2 5 1 4 7 , if right node is kept before left node the output is 3 5 2 7 4 1.

I have no clue what is causing such behavior.
This question has been asked on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/30-days-of-code/challenges/day-23-review-and-binary-trees/)

Given input is

```
     3
   /   \
  2     5
 / \     \
1   4     7
```

My Code

```
import sys
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.right=self.left=None
        self.data = data
class Solution:
    def insert(self,root,data):
        if root==None:
            return Node(data)
        else:
            if data<=root.data:
                cur=self.insert(root.left,data)
                root.left=cur
            else:
                cur=self.insert(root.right,data)
                root.right=cur
        return root

    def levelOrder(self,root):
        #Write your code here
        lisT = []
        i = 0
        lisT.append(root)

        while i < len(lisT):
            if root.left:
                lisT.append(root.left)
            if root.right:
                lisT.append(root.right)

            i += 1
            #print('i=',i,' len(lisT)=',len(lisT))
            try:
                root = lisT[i]
            except Exception as e:
                i = len(lisT)
        for each in lisT:
            print(each.data, end=' ')

            T=int(input())
myTree=Solution()
root=None
for i in range(T):
    data=int(input())
    root=myTree.insert(root,data)
myTree.levelOrder(root)
```

Comment: Which part isn't to understand? That's expected behavior for a BFS.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, the part where appending in the *list* as root, left  and right but when printing from the list it prints root, right and left.

Answer (score 0):

You have given youself the explanation. If you go from right to left, you get every level in reverse. 2 5 -> 5 2 and 1 4 7 -> 7 4 1.

For the solution, you should also think about a queue. Using first-in-first-out, you can append left and right branch in each level (if not None) and then take the first element of your list to print out the next level. When the queue is empty, you're done.

As an additional point, you should avoid `except Exception` and be more specific about the Exception, in this case `IndexError`. That's general coding style to prevent exception handlings which you don't want to handle (like KeyboardInterrupt).

Comment: Thanks Abufari, I will keep in mind regarding the exceptions.  
if you noticed the code, the next element is being appended to the end of the list and while reading, its being read from index 0, which makes it FIFO  
I need to understand the behavior, why going right to left the element are reversed.  
My understanding is, I am appeding the  _root, left and then right_ in a list, but when printing from the list, it prints the _root, right and then left_,  
The question is what is causing this behavior.